# ffmpeg concat command not reading input file correctly

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

I am trying to concatenate two video files using ffmpeg, and I am receiving an error.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy concat.mp4
```

And the error output I receive is....

```
[concat @ 0x7ff922000000] Line 1: unknown keyword '43.mp4'
list.txt: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: Seem to be missing keyword `file`. See format of text file at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer

Answer (score 3):

It looks like that the file names in the list have to be specially formatted to look like:

**file '/path/to/file1.wav'**

with a word **file** included. I spent a lot of time trying to guess why ffmpeg encountered an error trying to read the file names. It didn't matter if they were in the list or in the command line. So only after I utilized a command

```
for f in *.wav; do echo "file '$f'" >> mylist.txt; done
```

to make list from ffmpeg's manual I had success. The only difference was an additional word **file**.

Here you can read it yourself: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer